# TF behaviour showing delay when using ros::Time::now() vs. ros::Time(0)

Tags: ros, transforms, timestamp, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My situation is that I have `/tf` topic publishing the following frame transforms:

- A to B
- B to C
- C to D

My goal is to create a simple C++ program which extracts the transform A to D at the current time (i.e. `ros::Time::now()`). I call E the extracted target frame, and ideally E should coincide with D at each 10 Hz update of the while loop that I am using to listen in on the `/tf` topic. Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_measurement_jumping_debug");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  tf::TransformListener tf_listener;
  tf::TransformBroadcaster tf_broadcaster;
  tf::StampedTransform transform;

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    loop_rate.sleep();
    try
    {
      // Get the current transform from A to D
      ros::Time tf_time = ros::Time::now();
      tf_listener.waitForTransform("A", "D", tf_time, ros::Duration(3.0));
      tf_listener.lookupTransform("A", "D", tf_time, transform);
      // Publish back what I got
      transform.child_frame_id_ = "E"; // Rename to not overwrite D
      tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(transform);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex)
    {
      ROS_ERROR_STREAM(ex.what());
    }
  }
}
```

The result is not satisfactory as shown in the following screen recording:

[image: image description]

There is some kind fo delay in the transform from frame A to E. The reason I think that this is a delay issue is because if I move frame B slowly enough, then E more or less coincides with D (note that the transform B to C is rigid).

In the above code, if instead of `ros::Time tf_time = ros::Time::now();` I use `ros::Time tf_time = ros::Time(0);` then the result is what I want:

[image: image description]

My question is what is the cause of this? Ideally, I want a solution using `ros::Time::now()` because

1. What I am looking for is the *current* transform, not the *latest* transform;
2. When transforms stop arriving (e.g. because transform C to D is no longer being published) then the `ros::Time(0)` "hack" will keep sending the last transform prior to this event and I do not want that.

Thank you very much for your help. I have looked at the `/tf` tutorials and saw the [timestamp debugging section](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf%20problems#Checking_the_Timestamp) - however unfortunately none of it has so far helped me to resolve this problem.

**Update (tf_monitor output)**

Here's the output of `rosrun tf tf_monitor`:

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: B published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000125737 Max Delay: 0.0130457
Frame: C published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.00024707 Max Delay: 0.0130457
Frame: D published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.24257 Max Delay: 0.282611

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 196.535 Hz, Average Delay: 0.00547737 Max Delay: 0.276091
```

And here is the output of `rosrun tf tf_monitor A D`:

```
RESULTS: for A to D
Chain is: A -> B -> C -> D
Net delay     avg = 0.864727: max = 3.39458

Frames:
Frame: B published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -2.90574e-05 Max Delay: 0.0139616
Frame: C published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000132843 Max Delay: 0.0139616
Frame: D published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.236117 Max Delay: 0.288233

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 199.24 Hz, Average Delay: 0.00158674 Max Delay: 0.263055
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262349/tf-behaviour-showing-delay-when-using-ros::time::now()-vs.-ros::time(0)/) by [danyloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28384/danylom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked which transforms are published at which time with rosrun tf tf_monitor? When you call waitForTransform, I believe it waits for *all* of the transforms to be republished and this introduces some unnecessary delay.

You probably want to update E when even one of the transforms is new, so using ros::Time(0) is preferable until one of the transforms stops arriving. You should be able to check with `waitForTransform("A", "D", ros::Time::now()-0.5, ros::Duration(3.0))`, which should return false if the necessary transforms have been missing for more than 0.5 seconds. I'm not sure about the syntax though.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danyloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28384/danylom/) on 2017-05-24**:
I added an update to my original post with the output of `tf_monitor`. Indeed, I want to update E when even one of the transforms is new (e.g. the A to B transform, which updates much faster than the C to D transform). Does the `tf_monitor` output give any more clues?